# How to add whitelist public ip to squid proxy v 4.14 (windows 10)

Tags: squid

im use squid proxy in windows and i need to add whitelist public ip for access the squid server without basic authenication username or password

squid version : 4.14
OS : windows 10

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. If you have same problem, use the following solution:

1. Go to the `squid.conf` file and add

   ```
   acl publicusers src XX.XXX.XXX
   http_access allow publicusers
   http_access deny all
   ```
2. Replace this `XX.XXX.XXX` with your whitelisted public IP